# Best AI Approach for 2D to-down space shooter

Tags: ai-design, game-ai

I am building a 2d top-down space game, which involves several objects, such as asteroids, drones, spaceships, space litter and power-ups.
It follows the rules of space gravity, with speed and acceleration.
The idea is that a player controls his own spaceship, can fire bullets, and is allowed to spawn 3 support drones that will attack the enemy. Its goal is to deal the most damage to the opponent spaceship in 3 minutes.

It involves certain dynamics, such as "Destroying an asteroid spawns a power-up", "touching an asteroid deals damage to your spaceship" etc.

What would be the best approach to define an AI agent for it?

I was thinking of Reinforcement learning, but maybe the game is too complex and I wouldn't have the computational power for it?